# $facebook->getUser() returning 0

Tags: facebook

I've read loads of threads on this but there is either no answer or the answer given doesn't work for me.

I have the following code to ask the to authorize my facebook app if they haven't already authorized it. Once authorized, it should redirect to the same page but this time it shouldn't need to ask for authorization.

The code asks for user authorization perfectly...works exactly as I want, but when the app reloads $user is always set to 0.

Here's my code:

```
//Get PHP SDK
require_once 'facebook.php';
// Create our Application instance.
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
    'appId' => 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
    'secret' => 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
    'cookie' => true
));
    // Get User ID
    $user = $facebook->getUser();

    if ($user) {
        try {
            $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me');
            echo "logged in and authenticated";
        } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
            error_log($e);
            $user = null;
        }
    }

    // Ask for authorisation
    if(!$user) {
        $login_url = $facebook->getLoginUrl(
            array(
                'canvas' => 1,
                'fbconnect' => 0,
                'scope' => 'email,publish_stream',
                'redirect_uri' => 'myurl - same as Site URL in app basic settings'
            )
        );
        echo "<script> top.location.href='" . $login_url . "'</script>";
    }


}
```

After the user has authorized the app, it doesn't ask for authorization again so I'm assuming the authorization worked, but why is `$facebook->getUser()` returning 0?

The URL after the redirect has two query string parameters - 'state' and 'code'. Are they relevant? Should I be doing something with them? As far as I know I've downloaded the latest Facebook SDK so I'm at a loss on how to get this working.

Note: I'm calling the above code via AJAX.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I've sorted this.
The code does work, it's just the fact I'm running via ajax that's the problem.
Once I used it as a proper page load rather than an ajax call it all works :)